# How to evaluate these types of integral: $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \left[\sqrt{\int\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{121}{81}}dx}\right]dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1} [\sqrt{\int\sqrt{x^{2}+\frac{121}{81}}dx}]dx.$$ I am trying to evaluate this integral by substituting $x=\frac{11}{9}\tan(u)$. Therefore, $dx=\frac{11}{9}\sec^{2}(u)du$. Therefore the above integral will become $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{11}{9}\sec^{2}(u) [\sqrt{\int\frac{11}{9}\sec^{2}(u)\frac{11}{9}\sec(u)du}]du.$$ Therefore after this step the above integral will become $$\frac{11}{9}\int_{0}^{1}\sec^{2}(u)[\sqrt{\int\frac{121}{81}\sec^{3}(u)du}]du$$ for $\sec(u)>1$. The next step of the integral is $$\frac{11}{9}\int_{0}^{1}\sec^{2}(u)[\sqrt{\frac{121}{81}\int\sec^{3}(u)du}]du.$$The next step of the integral is $$\frac{121}{81}\int_{0}^{1}\sec^{2}(u)[\sqrt{\int\sec^{3}(u)du}]du.$$

Now let's integrate $\sec^{3}(u)$ separately.$$\int\sec^{3}(u)du=\frac{1}{2}[\sec(u)\tan(u)+\ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|]+C.$$ Therefore the above integral will become
$$\frac{121}{81}\int_{0}^{1}\sec^{2}(u)[\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}[\sec(u)\tan(u)+\ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|]+C}]du.$$

But I can't proceed further. Also I think we have to consider $\sec(u)<1$. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: WA is giving answer : $0.753416$. But the procedure  is not given.

Comment: You have created a new tag

Comment: Where is Plus C in the first integral?

Comment: Yes I forgot to write $+C$@BobDobbs

Comment: where did you get the original integral from?

Comment: This question is being asked in my elder brother's University. Currently he is pursuing PhD in mathematics in UNIVERSITY OF CALICUT.

Comment: You have a $\sqrt{x^2+ a^2}dx$,  suggesting  the substitution $x\to a \sinh u $. The rest is trivial.

Comment: An indefinite integral inside a definite integral is not a well-formed expression.

Comment: $\int \sqrt{x^2+\frac{121}{81}}\, dx=\dfrac{121\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{81x^2+121}+9x\right|\right)+9x\sqrt{81x^2+121}}{162}+C$

$\sqrt{\int \sqrt{x^2+\frac{121}{81}}\, dx}=\sqrt{\dfrac{121\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{81x^2+121}+9x\right|\right)+9x\sqrt{81x^2+121}}{162}+C}$

$\int_0^1\left(\sqrt{\int \sqrt{x^2+\frac{121}{81}}\, dx}\,\right)dx=\int_0^1\sqrt{\dfrac{121\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{81x^2+121}+9x\right|\right)+9x\sqrt{81x^2+121}}{162}+C}\,dx$

.....?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=11/9$, and make the change of variable $y=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x$, so $x+y=\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$. Squaring both sides yields $2xy+y^2=a^2$, so $2x = a^2/y-y$ and $-2dx = a^2/y^2+1$. Moreover, $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}= y+x = (1/2)(a^2/x+x)$. Hence
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2} dx = -\frac{1}{4} \int \Big( \frac{a^2}{y}+y \Big) \Big( \frac{a^2}{y^2}+1 \Big) dy = -\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{(a^2+y^2)^2}{y^3} dy.$$
$$\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2} dx = -\frac{1}{8} \Big( -\frac{a^4}{y^3} + 2a^2 \ln y+ y\Big) + C.$$
One may replace $y$ by $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x$ and integrate again with the same change of variables. All functions to be integrated are rational fractions, but a term
$$\int \ln y \times \Big( \frac{a^2}{y^2}+1 \Big) dy,$$
which can be integrated by parts.

Comment: But my question is of the form of $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\int{\sqrt{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx}}dx$.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think you cannot have a closed form for the antiderivative of the square root of the function obtained. Anyway, you have to precise what is the lower bound in the integral inside, otherwise as noted by Greg Martin, the function to be integrated is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

we will solve a more general case of this question ,initially, and then proceed to solve for this case.
suppose :
$$I = \int{\sqrt{\int{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}dx}dx}$$
via hyperbolic sub. we have:
$$x = a\sinh u \Rightarrow dx = a\cosh u du$$
$$
I = \int{\sqrt{\int{a\cosh^2 u}du}dx}
$$
$$J = \int{a\cosh^2 u}du = \frac{a}{4}\int{e^{2u} + 2 + e^{-2u} du} = \frac{a}{8}e^{2u} + \frac{a}{2}u - \frac{a}{8}e^{-2u} + C = \frac{a}{4}(2u+\sinh(2u)) + C$$
and with $u = \sinh^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$ we have $J = \frac{a}{4}(2\sinh^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+2\frac{x}{a}\sqrt{1+x^2}) + C$
Now to solve for $I$ :
$$
I = \int{\sqrt{\int{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}dx}dx} = \int \sqrt{J} dx = \int{\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}(\sinh^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+\frac{x}{a}\sqrt{1+(\frac{x}{a})^2}) + C} dx}
$$
this integral does not have an elementary answer and therefore there is no closed form for it.

Comment: How about using special non-elementary functions?